# Why is my std::string getting converted to std::basic_string<char>?

Tags: c++, stack

> **Error**

```
stack.cc:53:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘Stack<std::basic_string<char> >::push(std::string)’
stack.cc:53:28: note: candidate is:
stack.cc:32:11: note: Stack<T>& Stack<T>::push(T&) [with T = std::basic_string<char>]
```

> **stack.cc**

```
#include<iostream>

template <typename T>
class Stack {
private:
    T* array_;
    int length_;
    T* last_;
    void expandArray();

public:
    Stack(int length = 8) {
        array_   = new T[length];
        length_  = length;
        last_    = array_;
    }

    Stack<T>& push(T&);
    T pop();
};

template<typename T>
void Stack<T>::expandArray() {
    T* array_temp = new T[length_ << 1];
    memcpy(array_temp, array_, length_);
    std::swap(array_, array_temp);
    delete[] array_temp;
    length_ <<= 1;
}

template<typename T>
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::push(T& data) {
    if (last_ == (array_ + length_ - 1)) {
        expandArray();
    }
    last_[0] = data;
    last_++;
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
T Stack<T>::pop() {
    if(array_ != last_) {
        T temp = last_[0];
        last_--;
        return temp;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    Stack<std::string> s;
    s.push(std::string("a"))
     .push(std::string("b"))
     .push(std::string("c"))
     .push(std::string("d"));
    std::cout << s.pop() << std::endl;
    std::cout << s.pop() << std::endl;
    std::cout << s.pop() << std::endl;
    std::cout << s.pop() << std::endl;
}
```

Wanted to understand why a conversion is happening from `std::string` to `std::basic_string<char>`?

Please feel free to comment on the code quality as well.

Comment: `std::string` is a type definition for `std::basic_string<char>`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual problem is that you're attempting to pass a reference to an object created in the argument rather than stored in a variable. See that `T&` argument to `Stack<T>::push`? You cannot pass your temporary here because it's a non-`const` reference. Try as follows...

```
Stack<T>& push(const T&);
```

Use this signature for your implementation, too.

---

That being said, know that `std::string` is a mere typedef over `std::basic_string<char>`. This is because the functionality for strings can be extended to the other character types, too -- `std::wstring` for `wchar_t`, `std::u16string` for `char16_t`, and `std::u32string` for `char32_t`. ;-)

See **§21.4 Class template `basic_string` [basic.string]** of the C++11 specification.

> ```
> // basic_string typedef names
> typedef basic_string<char> string;
> typedef basic_string<char16_t> u16string;
> typedef basic_string<char32_t> u32string;
> typedef basic_string<wchar_t> wstring;
> ```

Note that you shouldn't rely on `iostream` to include `string` for you. You should also include `cstring` and specify the scope for your `memcpy` call.

---

By the way, you should really look into using an initializer list for `Stack`'s constructor... see as follows.

```
Stack(int length = 8) : length_(length), array_(new T[length]), last_(array_) { }
```

Note that this functioning properly on `array_` preceding `last_` as a class member declaration ;-)

---

... *AND* a final note. Your `pop` is incorrect, since you're returning the element *past* the top. Instead, try something as follows...

```
template<typename T>
T Stack<T>::pop() {
    if (array_ != last_) {
        return *--last_;
    }
    /* other stuff here */
}
```

You need to decrement *prior* to dereferencing, since `last_` points past the top. As a side note, you're also returning a copy of the `std::string` from `pop`, even though you stated you wanted to avoid as such.

Note you shouldn't be returning `NULL` since this isn't a pointer type. In fact, you'll just be creating an `std::string` via the constructor that takes a `const char *`... which is explicitly prohibited in the case of `NULL`. See §21.4.2¶8-9...

> ```
> basic_string(const charT* s, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
> ```
>
> *Requires:* `s` shall not be a null pointer.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, what is the right way to resolve the reference to temporary issue? I want to use a reference and do not want to have the overhead of a string copy.

Comment: @Moeb declare it a `const` reference

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` is a typedef for `std::basic_string<char>` it is not being converted to it, it is it. The reason is that the same `std::basic_string` template can be used with `wchar_t` to have unicode strings.

Comment: Just tacking this on here: see `std::wstring`, `std::u16string`, `std::u32string`.

Comment: `wchar_t` != unicode, and `char` does not preclude unicode.  `std::string` is perfectly capable of storing unicode strings in utf-8, which is hands down the superior encoding.

Comment: -1 because `wstring` is a billion miles from Unicode support.

Answer (score 1):

Because that is what `std::string` really is - it is just an alias for `std::basic_string':

```
typedef basic_string<char> string;
```

When the compiler is reporting the error message, it is displaying the typedef's real base type, not the alias name.